# Does function prototyping impact performance?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-prototypes

I'm curious as to, aside from maintainability, there are any real advantages of function prototyping. At this stage I can only se that it is useful for reading the program but can not find information as to whether the execution is affected because of prototyping.

Comment: If you neglect to prototype and instead define a function in a header file, the compiler can choose to inline such functions in which case the run-time performance of the program can be affected. Affected could mean *slower* or it could mean *faster*. This might not be the answer to the question you're trying to ask. dasblinkenlight has it right about the simple case of a single-file program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does function prototyping impact performance?

Not at all. Function prototypes only define interfaces. They are not executable code. Executable code lies in implementations of those interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Having a prototype vs. a definition ahead of the point of call makes no difference in generated code.

Prototypes are necessary for the compiler to make proper conversions at the point of call. Once the compiler has finished, the fact that there was a prototype makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

DVDT,

Prototyping is very useful when separating your code into separate files. Additionally, to use function libraries in your program you'll usually need to create prototypes for the functions in the libraries. Lastly, some compilers read top-down, so a prototype must be included at the top of the file to enable functions that otherwise appear in the wrong order, to work. (not "Wrong" really, just in a different order for that particular instance). I've also been liberal with my definitions in this answer.

Strictly speaking though, these mechanisms are all part of "execution".

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still unsure whether prototyping will impact the performance of a program.

Comment: I don't think it will, unless you're going to use them to dynamically load libraries or use define function pointers - but then they may not be considered "prototypes" at that point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Function prototyping causes the compiler to flag improper calls to a function.  Yes, "machine" efficiency is unaffected.  On the other hand, programmer productivity might gain from knowing the potential source of a problem.